# Fill a List of Bitmaps with just a sample image resource (added to drawable folder)?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android

I have a view model exposing a list of `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` (if there is something else better, please let me know, thanks).

So in reality, the images data will be fetched from some service (represented as bytes), the bytes then will be converted to `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` - I've not tested that case to see if there is any problem. Now in development (on client side) process, I would like to use just 1 sample image resource added to the `drawable` folder. If exposing some list of resource ids to help show the images, everything is just fine. However what exposed is a list of `Android.Graphics.Bitmap`, and I've tried using `BitmapFactory.DecodeResource` method to convert the added image resource id to a Bitmap, like this:

```
//in the context of some Activity
var images = new List<Bitmap>();
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    var bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.SampleImage);
    images.Add(bm);
}
```

The code above runs throwing an `OutOfMemoryException` (at the line `var bm...`).

I'm just a beginner in Android programming, so it's really hard for me to solve this problem. The exception is clear, looks like the memory is limited but I don't like to reduce the image size, resolution or something to make the code run (because if showing the images via resource id, everything is just fine, the image is shown with just what it should be without any degradation in quality).

I think java developer can also help with this, here is the code in java:

```
//don't need to add the bitmap to any list, just like this will 
//throw the exception
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sampleImage);
    //...
}
```

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

Per my deeper debugging, the exception is thrown at the 20th loop (i=19). Also the device I'm using is an emulator (Visual Studio Emulator for Android), maybe that's some kind of limit of the emulator. I'm not sure how it will be for actual physical device. BUT I can run many apps (even a 3D game) in the emulator, so looks like the emulator is just fine.

Comment: is the loop condition meant to be `i < 30`? and do you really need `Bitmap`s or are `Drawable`s fine?

Comment: @oldrinb yes, thank you, it's a typo, I typed everything, not copied and pasted.

Comment: how frequently is this bitmap-decode loop occurring? once?

Comment: As I said I expose a list of `Bitmap` in my view model, so `Drawable` may not be what I want. Of course if you show it's possible to convert `bytes` (loaded from service) to `Drawable` and the performance is acceptable, then it will be OK.

Comment: The loop runs just 1 time, not even 1 time successful. The image size is just about 140 KB

Comment: they're all `Bitmap`s of the same image?

Comment: @oldrinb yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve (for testing purpose only), when deploying, the real images are shown instead. I'm working on client side project (mainly in phase of designing UI), so I just need to show a list of images (showing the same sample image).

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `Bitmap`'s are alloc'd, their memory size has nothing to do with their compressed on disk size as once in memory they become (width x height x 4 bytes (i.e. ARGB_8888) ) in size. So 30 images of just 1000x500 dimensions will be over 60MB of ram. What dimensions are your images?

Comment: @SushiHangover yes maybe I'm wrong at that point (because some images are compressed, but when they are loaded the memory will be expanded). The image resolution is `640x540`, so it should not occupy too much RAM.

Answer (score 0):

you are flooding the memory provided for you with your bitmaps. you should take a look at [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load images efficiently and also the recycler view to reduce the burden of loading images.

Comment: Firstly I understand that the memory is limited, although I'm really surprised with the amount of `19 * 140KB = 2660KB`, while an app may consume 50MB RAM or even more. It's just some kind of limit ***designed*** in Android, not by the device. What I'm looking for is a solution (as I said, show demo images (loaded into `Bitmap`) from just 1 sample image (added to `drawable`), not really an explanation. Also BTW does `Picasso` library support loading images from some web service? (not from URL because the images are saved directly in some database). Thanks